# Проверка входных параметров в конструкторе

Tags: java

Требуется осуществить проверку входных параметров в конструкторе класса.
`i` и `j` должны быть больше нуля. Насколько эффективна проверка вот в таком виде?
Есть ли более оптимальный способ?
Будет ли корректно вот так выбросить исключение в блоке `try` и самому же его перехватить?

```
public MyConstructor(int i, int j){

    try{
       if (!((i>0)&&(j>0))){

              throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       }

    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){

        System.out.printf("Неверное использование конструктора. ");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
}
```

Comment: не нужно ловить исключение в конструкторе, пусть оно выбрасывается на верх. System.exit(0); - плохая практика. Для ошибок есть отдельный метод System.err.printf. Если предоставляете API просто выбрасывается unchecked exception, если для себя, осуществляйте проверку с помощью assert

Comment: DaysLikeThis спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бросать исключение в конструкторе - нормальная практика, но не нужно его ловить там же - это забота для тех, кто будет создавать объект.

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass (int i, int j){
        if (i < 0 || j < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("i and j can't be negative");
        }

        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
}

// В другом месте
MyClass obj = null;
try {
    obj = new MyClass(-1, -1);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.err.printf("Unable to create MyClass instance: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: тогда вопрос: Что работает быстрее и эффективнее? if (!((i>0)&&(j>0))) - это, или то, что у Вас if (i < 0 || j < 0).  Нашел вот это - Логические операнды && и || - это укороченные версии операторов & и |. Отличие заключается в том, что например в укороченной версии (или), если первый операнд имеет значение (true), то выражение сразу становится (true) и второй операнд даже не рассматривается. То же самое и с (и), если первый операнд имеет ложное значение (false), то и все выражение сразу становится (false), второй операнд не рассматривается.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что более эффективно && или ||   ?

Comment: @java_jun это забота не для тех, кто пишет программу. Этим занимается компилятор, и будьте уверены в том, что сделает он это самым лучшим способом. Когда пишете условия, думайте о том, чтобы их можно было нормально прочитать - у меня не получилось за пару секунд понять, что ваше условие значит, и не хотелось прокручивать в голове его работу, прочитать условие задачи в вопросе оказалось проще.

Comment: therainycat  -  аргумент хороший, убедили. Спасибо. Напишу как у Вас.

Answer (score 0):

Так не принято делать. Конструктор это конструктор - создали, значит создали, а верно или неверно это другая история.

Чтобы решить такую проблемы принято писать так:

```
public class MyClass {
   private int i;
   private MyClass(int i) {
      this.i=i;
   }

   public static MyClass getInstance(int i) {
      if(i<=0)
         return null;
      return new MyClass(i);
   }
}
```

Поборники *ДавайтеВсеРазложимПоПолочкам* иногда называют это паттерном *getInstance* или [factory](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)

Comment: Barmaley, большое спасибо. Проблема в том, что по условию задачи мне необходимо реализовать проверку в конструкторе и в нем же бросить исключение. Задачу я придумал не сам. Она тестовая. DaysLikeThis подсказывает, что не нужно ловить исключение в конструкторе. Получается оставляю только блок if  с проверкой и внутри него бросаю исключение.

Comment: Factory, как правило, используется для создания объектов разных классов. Автору нужно создать объект этого же класса, но предварительно проверить аргументы. Для этого достаточно сделать то же, что делал он, но не ловить исключение. Не знаю, у кого так принято, но даже первый кусок исходника openjdk, который выпал в Google, показывает, как они используют проверки в исходниках: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/Buffer.java

Comment: Ну началось - это уже чистой воды холивар, есть сторонники бросания в конструкторе, есть сторонники лайтовости конструктора ну и т.д. - я сторонник лайтовости :)

Comment: Классика жанра исходные тексты класса [Calendar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) - тот же OpenJDK, но в конструкторе ничего не бросается, хотя можно было бы

Comment: @Barmaley это не холивар. В Calendar нет проверок, поэтому и исключения не бросаются. Я мог бы написать еще целую скатерть текста, но буду краток - я бы не писал, что так не принято делать, потому что так все-таки пишут.

Comment: Я тоже могу написать хорошую книгу об этом, но не буду, расстанемся друзьями :)